# git cached file is outside repository

Tags: git, command-line, ubuntu-16.04

Out of the blue, git started to track `~/.config/chromium` directory. My repository's path looks something like this: `~/app/my-project`. My guess is that Chromium directory was added to a repo because I launched Chromium with disabled web security flag from the my-project directory. I tried to remove it with `git rm --cached ~/.config`, but then I get the error

> fatal: /home/user/.config: '/home/user/.config' is outside repository

Any ideas how can it track it and at the same time claim it's outside the repository? And how can I fix this? I'd rather avoid deleting my ~/.config directory.

git status:

```
src/pages/Page.js
~/.config/chromium/Default/Cache/xyz
~/.config/chromium/Default/Cache/abc
~/.config/chromium/Local State
```

Comment: Are you sure its tracking the chromium directory inside your config directory? This is highly unusual behaviour. Isn't it tracking directory called `~` inside your project?

Comment: What does `git status` look like?

Comment: Ferrybig, this is it! Somehow ~ was created and git relates to it, my guess is when I was launching Chromium from my app directory. I may pure-hearted remove it. Panchock, I'll update my question with my `git status`, but it looked like it was referring to home.

Comment: @Ferrybig Could you post that as an answer so Dune can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You accidentally created a file called `~` inside your git project, and are now confused by the fact that you think the `~` refers to your home directory.

To delete this file, just quote the path:

```
git rm --cached "~/.config"
```